# Iphone X translation animation issue swift/xcode

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation, iphone-x

Only occurs in iphone X

I'm making a view appear and disappear from bottom of screen using CGAffinetransform(translationY), everything works fine in every devices but in iphone x. Two labels in a stack view as a subview of a uiview when animating labels start from 20px higher then animation starts.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.stackOrderDetailsContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: self.stackOrderDetailsContainer.frame.size.height)
            self.blackTransparentView.transform = .identity
            self.blackTransparentView.alpha = 0
            self.viewArrowHolder.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-2*Double.pi))
        }, completion: nil)
```

edit: Added code snippet

Comment: Please provide code snipped where you do layout and animation.

Comment: putting labels in another view instead of stack view solved it